# When i am using soup. Find(p)['class'] its is saying literal['class'] cannot be assigns to the type 'SupportsIndex' slice

Tags: beautifulsoup, htmlparse

[image]

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

url = "https://www.codewithharry.com"

r = requests.get(url)

htmlContent = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('p')['class'])
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to find the class used in that paragraph and the output is shown also but there is a error shown that the literal class cannot be assigned to the supportsIndex so I want to know why it is showing

Comment: Okay, what does `soup.find('p')` give?

Comment: It give me the first paragraph of the website

Comment: What does `soup.find('p').attrs` give?

Comment: it gives an error saying that 'attrs' is not a known member of "none" and with the error it also give me the result "{'class': ['mt-2', 'text-sm', 'text-gray-500', 'md:text-base']}"

Comment: strange? Perhaps attach screenshots to the question. Anyway, try `first_p=soup.find('p'); print(first_p.get('class'))`

Comment: It is showing the same output as before "['mt-2', 'text-sm', 'text-gray-500', 'md:text-base']" but giving the error as **cannot access member for type NavigableString**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code showed me a warning in vs code for the written code and the output that was given was correct so you can just write there as shown below:

`print (soup. Find('p')['class'])  # type: ignore`

**Sometimes it show the warning in the terminal in vs code so you can use this to stop the error**